# How do I save everything on my phone and clear iCloud storage?

Tags: iphone, icloud

I have an iPhone X with 256 GB of storage, which is a lot. However I have very little iCloud storage. How can I save everything that is on my phone, to my phone, and then clear iCloud and wipe it clean? I know that iCloud provides a backup and a way to see things from different devices, but I won't lose my phone, and I can probably find a way to upload single files to iCloud.

I have tried not letting the device upload to iCloud, but the AppleID and iCloud section on settings is grayed out (parental controls) and when I tried it on laptop it just cut off the connection without saving to the device or clearing the space on iCloud.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Although I am unfamiliar with the workings of parental controls, I would imagine it's possible to access (a part of) the data stored on iCloud Drive via the Files app. It is then possible to move said data to your "On my iPhone" folder, which will save it to your local file system.

As for the other data: Have you asked your parents for help with removing the data from iCloud? They will most likely have to (temporarily) disable your parental controls, after which you should be able to choose what is synced to iCloud. It should then also be possible to delete said data.

On an unrelated note: I would recommend creating a backup of your iPhone to your laptop. However unlikely, iPhones (as all electronic devices) can die unexpectedly. Having a backup is useful in such cases. If you give more information on the "cutoff" as you described, I would be happy to help with that as well.